# Simple Terrain and Terrain Following Camera Implementation in LibGDX

Tags: libgdx

I apologize if this topic is duplicated, but I not find something simple on other topics.

I'm new in 3D with LibGDX and I'm trying to make a basic implementation of a `3D Terrain` (even very simple, only an inclined plane) and a `Terrain Following Camera`.

I've googled but not found an example so simple as well for a beginner.

Can anyone give me an example code or indicate where I can find?
I've tried to use this: https://github.com/eerock/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/TerrainTest.java, but it does not work, because I'm using the `LibGDX 1.9.3` with OpenGL 2.0.

Thanks in advance for any help.